# get values from another Java class

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I want to get doktor[0], doktor[1], secilenBolum from `RandevufiltreSorgu.java`. I created object of `RandevufiltreSorgu` class in randevusec. But when I run the query, I am not able to obtain the values I want. There is no inheritance in use. What can I do?

```
public class randevusec {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    public ResultSet saatler() throws SQLException, Exception {
        randevufiltreSorgu nesne = new randevufiltreSorgu();
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tipmerkezivt", "postgres", "2569");
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(
                    "WITH Q1 AS(\n" + "    select * from doktor natural join bolum where dr_adi='" + nesne.doktor[0]
                            + "' and dr_soyadi='" + nesne.doktor[1] + "' and bolum.b_adi='" + nesne.secilenBolum + "'\n"
                            + "    )\n" + "    select cs_saat from doktorun_programi natural join Q1\n" + "    ",
                    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            return rs;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Bağlantı başarısız!");
        }

        finally {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the type of doktor ?is it a string ?

Comment: You should look up a JDBC tutorial which describes how to do this properly with prepared statements etc. In general it's bad practice to declare JDBC resources such as result sets or statements as fields in a class or pass them around between methods because these should have a minimal scope (you want to close/release them as soon as possible). Depending on your JDBC driver implementation, because you're calling `conn.close();` always at the end of the method, the result set will probably get closed as well. Instead of returning the result set, iterate through it and return a POJO collection.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to understand your code because it is mostly in foreign language, but what you can do is when you construct `doktor[0]` and `doktor[1]`, put the keyword `public static` before them.